# What happens to the timestamp of a message in a stream when it's mapped into another stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I've an application where I process a stream and convert it into another. Here is a sample:

```
public void run(final String... args) {
    final Serde<Event> eventSerde = new EventSerde();

    final Properties props = streamingConfig.getProperties(
        applicationName,
        concurrency,
        Serdes.String(),
        eventSerde
    );

    props.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, EXACTLY_ONCE);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, EventTimestampExtractor.class);

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<String, Event> eventStream = builder.stream(inputStream);

    final Serde<Device> deviceSerde = new DeviceSerde();

    eventStream
        .map((key, event) -> {
            final Device device = modelMapper.map(event, Device.class);

            return new KeyValue<>(key, device);
        })
        .to("device_topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), deviceSerde));

    final Topology topology = builder.build();
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

    streams.start();
}
```

Here are some details about the app:

```
Spring Boot 1.5.17
Kafka 2.1.0
Kafka Streams 2.1.0
Spring Kafka 1.3.6
```

Although a timestamp is set in the messages inside the input stream, I also place an implementation of TimestampExtractor to make sure that a proper timestamp is attached into all messages (as other producers may send messages into the same topic).

Within the code, I receive a stream of events and I basically convert them into different objects and eventually route those objects into different streams.

I'm trying to understand whether the initial timestamp I set is still attached to the messages published into device_topic in this particular case.

The receiving end (of device stream) is like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "device_topic")
public void onDeviceReceive(final Device device, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) final long timestamp) {
    log.trace("[{}] Received device: {}", timestamp, device);
}
```

Unfortunetely the printed timestamp seems to be wall clock time. Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: For your example, the input record timestamp should be copied to the output record. Not sure what `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP)` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Kafka 1.3.x uses a very old 0.11 client; perhaps it doesn't propagate the timestamp. I just tested with Boot 2.1.3 and Spring Kafka 2.2.4 and the timestamp is propagated ok...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class So54771130Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54771130Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so54771130", 0, 42L, null, "baz");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> stream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("so54771130");
        stream
            .map((k, v) -> {
                System.out.println("Mapping:"  + v);
                return new KeyValue<>(null, "bar");
            })
            .to("so54771130-1");
        return stream;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic("so54771130", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return new NewTopic("so54771130-1", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so54771130", topics = "so54771130-1")
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts) {
        System.out.println(in + "@" + ts);
    }

}
```

and

```
Mapping:baz
bar@42
```

Comment: Kafka Streams copies input record timestamp to output records since it's first release (ie, 0.10.0.0).

Comment: Yes, I just tested it with Boot 1.5.x, Spring Kafka 1.3.8 and the 0.11.0.2 streams jar and it worked fine too.